# how to fix magento 1.9.3 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: productId

Tags: product, magento1.9.3, error-message

Hi Magento log show ERROR `Notice: Undefined variable: productId  in /home/myhomestoreco/public_html/app/code/local/Sm/Cartpro/controllers/IndexController.php on line 31`

Comment: check your variable is wrong in line 31

Comment: You are not getting the product in the controller for some reason or you have some spelling mistake while calling the object of the product